# Get component dynamically in method and set its property in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am a developing an ionic game, How can i get the properties of a child component(app-square) in a method in the parent component(app-board). app-board as over 30 app-square components, so i want it to be able to dynamically access it
board-component.html(parent)

```
<app-square (click)="makeMove(l1)" [count]="3" #l1></app-square>
  <app-square #l2></app-square>
```

board-component.ts

```
makeMove(obj: SquareComponent){
//I want to change the value of l2 here
    }
```

I understand i cannot use ViewChild as it doesn't work inside methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference it using `ViewChildren` decorator inside board component like this

```
@ViewChildren(QuareComponent)
squareComp:QueryList<SquareComponent>;
```

and then inside your method just use it

```
makeMove(){
  console.log(this.squareComp.toArray()) //here are all your square components
}
```

Comment: thanks, like i said there are over 30 app-square components. So i have to declare 30 components this way. Is this the only way to do?